# Visual Studio 2008\Backup Files folder created when every new VS instance is opened

Tags: visual-studio-2008, backup, registry, autosave

I think I have something broken with the path that VS 2008 saves the backup files. Since few days, it creates a new "Visual Studio 2008" directory in the same folder that my .sln file exists. Then, after the time of the first auto-save expires, the backup files are being saved to this folder.

I browsed the tools-options dialog but I haven't found a way to set the directory to by static: C:\documents and setings\\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Backup Files.

Can anybody point me with the right solution to this problem (probably the correct registry entry - I guess) ?
thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check here:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0

Fixing the paths there should do the trick, take a special look at **VisualStudioLocation** which by default points to *%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2008*

Comment: This was very irritating. Thank you for the fix.

Comment: Works with VS 2010 as well (replace 9.0 with 10.0).